# Core Plot annotation touch event

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am using `Core Plot` in my application.
I need to make the `CPTAnnotation` objects for a plot respond to a user's touch event. 
What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`CPPlotSpaceDelegate` protocol is used  touches event set the delgate

you need to call this below method in your view controller

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point;

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceCancelledEvent:(id)event;

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point;

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

For annotation tap you need to use like that...

```
- (void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
NSLog(@"touch");
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;

if (_annotation)
{
    [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:_annotation];
    _annotation = nil;
}

CPTMutableTextStyle *annotationTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
annotationTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
annotationTextStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
annotationTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";

NSValue *value = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
NSString *number1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", point.x];
NSString *number2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", point.y];

NSLog(@"x and y are, %.2f, %.2f", point.x, point.y);
NSLog(@"number1 and number2 are, %.2f, %.2f", point.x, point.y);

NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.x];
NSNumber *y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:point.y];

NSArray *anchorPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: x, y, nil];

NSString *final = [number1 stringByAppendingString:number2];
NSLog(@"final is %@",final);


CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:final style:annotationTextStyle];
_annotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
_annotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
_annotation.displacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
[graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:_annotation];
}
```

Comment: Hi Spynet, thank you for your response. But I was wondering how can we handle a touch event on an annotation object. For example, if I have an image there and I want some actions after the users taps on it. Your example shows how to handle touches on plot symbol at some index. Is there a similar delegate method for CPTAnnotation object? I can handle all touch events by using CPPlotSpaceDelegate methods and then check if there is some annotation for these coordinates. But that seems very tricky. I guess there's an elegant way for this.

Comment: `CPTAnnotation` defines the relationship between its host and content layer. The content layer can be any `CPTLayer` subclass, all of which have event handling methods inherited from the `<CPTResponder>` protocol. You could make a custom `CPTLayer` subclass for the annotation content to handle events, but you would also need to modify `CPTGraph` so that it passed the event on to the annotations in addition to the plots, plot spaces, etc. that it already does.

Comment: @EricSkroch, that makes sense. Can you please also explain how to force `CPTGraph` object to pass the event to the annotations?

Comment: As a subclass of `CPTAnnotationHostLayer`, a graph has an `annotations` property that contains all of the annotations attached to the graph. Modify `-pointingDeviceDownEvent:atPoint:` and the other event-handling methods to pass the event to the content layer of every annotation if the point is inside the content `frame`.

Answer (score 0):

*CPTAnnotation* contains contentLayer property, type of the property is *CPTLayer*, *SPTLayer* confirm interface *CPTResponder*.

You can create custom class for the content layer and override methods from *[CPRResponder](https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg-history/efa73ee50d8edfd0e1d4294cf4bd2c07d9f8af77/documentation/html/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_responder-p.html)* :

```
(BOOL)  - pointingDeviceDownEvent:atPoint:
(BOOL)  - pointingDeviceUpEvent:atPoint:
(BOOL)  - pointingDeviceDraggedEvent:atPoint:
(BOOL)  - pointingDeviceCancelledEvent:
```